# Auto resize innerWidth & innerHeight based on the viewport when using the Colorbox jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, lightbox, colorbox

I am using the latest version of the Colorbox jquery plugin to open an iframe - I'd like to have this open and resize correctly depending on the size of the viewport, this is what I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:640, innerHeight:390});
});
```

Any ideas to have this open up at a suitable size for mobile etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify what that meant exactly. this will make it 100% no matter what.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var w = $(window).innerWidth();
    var h = $(window).innerHeight();

   $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth: w, innerHeight:h});
});

$(window).resize( function(){ 

    var w = $(window).innerWidth();
    var h = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('.youtube').css('width',w,'height',h)

});
```

Comment: I also found maxWidth & maxHeight colorbox attributes but i'll accept your answer as it is clear & concise.